# soup.find_all me devuelve array vacio []

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Estoy tratando de obtener todos los links de los cursos en esta pagina https://cursosdev.com/coupons, pero al ejecutar mi script me devuelve un array vacío []. He estado probando en otras paginas web y si funciona, pero raramente en esta pagina no me funciona, alguna opción que me este saltando?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://cursosdev.com/coupons'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#Extraccion
eq = soup.find_all('a', class_='c-card block bg-white shadow-md hover:shadow-xl rounded-lg overflow-hidden'.replace(' ','.'))

print(eq)
```

Comment: no se por que pasa eso pero las veces que me pasaba tenia que recargar la pagina web que quería ver y me traía todos los datos que quería extraer

Comment: tambien he recargado la pagina varias veces para que no haya problemas, pero aun asi no me devuelve nada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en que el servidor está bloqueando las peticiones del User-Agent de requests, si miras la respuesta que estás recibiendo, es un 403 forbidden.

```py
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

```html
<html>
    <head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
    <body>
        <center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
       <hr/><center>nginx</center>
   </body>
</html>
```

Es necesario que cambies el User-Agent a la hora de realizar la petición para saltarte la restricción, además, estás reemplazando los espacios por puntos en el string a buscar en find_all, por lo que, si hubiera algo, tampoco lo encontraría dado que las clases aparecen con espacios y no con puntos.

```py
page = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

eq = soup.find_all('a', class_='c-card block bg-white shadow-md hover:shadow-xl rounded-lg overflow-hidden')

print(eq[0])
```

```html
<a class="c-card block bg-white shadow-md hover:shadow-xl rounded-lg overflow-hidden" href="https://cursosdev.com/coupons-udemy/user-story-mapping">
<div class="relative pb-48 overflow-hidden">
<img alt="" class="absolute inset-0 h-full w-full object-cover" src="https://img-a.udemycdn.com/course/480x270/3517492_5a2a.jpg?mpC7CJCUb-ZWvv0iuR9MVpFFYt2pP9_oqTwMzkm1BcZt5SmXikGum5Dp0YIw_UKa4G9V8O--v5hoDlS8k4cdwgVdMUMejzvtNCTeyHowQGsrusEBsHrOojEFwAE3_Q"/>
<div class="absolute top-3 mb-2 ml-3 px-2 py-1 rounded text-sm text-white" style="background-color: rgb(67, 200, 1)">-100%</div>
</div>
<div class="p-4">
<div class="wx-auto grid grid-cols-2">
<div class="text-left"><span class="mx-2 text-sm text-red-600 font-bold">FREE</span><span class="line-through text-sm">$29.99</span></div>
<div class="mx-auto">
<img height="32" src="https://cursosdev.com/img/plantilla/logoudemy.png" width="32">
</img></div>
</div>
<h2 class="mt-2 mb-2 font-bold">User Story Mapping</h2>
<p class="text-sm">Creado por: <i>Susana Miranda</i></p>
<div class="mt-2 flex items-center text-sm text-gray-600">
<span class="inline-block text-white bg-bg-rating font-bold text-sm py-0 px-1 rounded">3.5</span>
<div class="relative inline-flex text-start">
<div class="absolute top-0 left-0 whitespace-no-wrap overflow-hidden w-0" style="width: 70%">
<div class="inline-flex">
<svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" stroke="none" viewbox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path>
</svg>
<svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" stroke="none" viewbox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path>
</svg>
<svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" stroke="none" viewbox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path>
</svg>
<svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" stroke="none" viewbox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path>
</svg>
<svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" stroke="none" viewbox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path>
</svg>
</div>
</div>
<svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewbox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path>
</svg>
<svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewbox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path>
</svg>
<svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewbox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path>
</svg>
<svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewbox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path>
</svg>
<svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewbox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path>
</svg>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="p-4 border-t border-b text-xs">
<div class="grid grid-cols-2">
<div>
<span class="focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline inline-block text-cool-gray-500 font-bold text-sm py-0 px-1 rounded-full">Spanish</span>
</div>
<div class="inline-flex items-center mx-auto">
<svg class="text-cool-gray-500 mr-2" height="14" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<path d="M0 10C0 4.47715 4.47715 0 10 0C12.6522 0 15.1957 1.05357 17.0711 2.92893C18.9464 4.8043 20 7.34784 20 10C20 15.5228 15.5228 20 10 20C4.47715 20 0 15.5228 0 10ZM10 18C5.58172 18 2 14.4183 2 10C2 5.58172 5.58172 2 10 2C14.4183 2 18 5.58172 18 10C18 12.1217 17.1571 14.1566 15.6569 15.6569C14.1566 17.1571 12.1217 18 10 18ZM10.88 4.5L10.88 9.64L14.51 13.27C14.7018 13.4678 14.7018 13.7822 14.51 13.98L13.98 14.51C13.7822 14.7018 13.4678 14.7018 13.27 14.51L9.27 10.51C9.17837 10.4159 9.12492 10.2912 9.12 10.16L9.12 4.5C9.12 4.22386 9.34386 4 9.62 4L10.38 4C10.6561 4 10.88 4.22386 10.88 4.5Z" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"></path>
</svg>
<span class="text-sm text-cool-gray-500 font-bold">hace 8 horas</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: una consulta por que a veces trae una lista vacía y luego cuando recargo la web me extrae lo que quiero ?

Comment: acabo de corregir lo que me comenta, pero sigue igual devolviéndome un array vacío.

Comment: una consulta más, en donde puedo ubicar el error 403 que me acaba de mostrar

Comment: Te sale un array vacío porque las clases que estás buscando en el contenido de la página web no está. Revisa las clases que estás buscando, o dime qué son esos cupones que necesitas y te ayudo a buscarlas. @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal

Comment: Imprime el contenido de soup sin modificar el User-Agent, ahí te saldrá el contenido de la respuesta HTTP:

Comment: @SalvadorMellado ¿Puedes concretar más? ¿A qué te refieres con vacía? ¿En qué caso?

Comment: @SalvadorMellado La clase que estan en la pagina son estas: c-card block bg-white shadow-md hover:shadow-xl rounded-lg overflow-hidden, En total son 18, pero no se por qué no me listan si estan en la pagina.

Comment: a mi me pasaba lo mismo tenia un código similar al tuyo y a veces me traía los resultados y a veces me traía solo una lista vacía pero cuando recargaba la pagina me traía la lista con todos los resultados y cuando volvía ejecutar el script me traía la lista vacía entonces tenia que estar recargando la pagina siempre que quería extraer los datos

Comment: El problema está en el replace, estás cambiando los espacios por puntos, por lo que no encuentra esas clases en el soup. Si eliminas el replace, aparecen los resultados. @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal

Comment: es verdad, pero me filtra con la clase que puse y con elementos de diferentes clases

Comment: ¿Cómo que no te filtra? He puesto un ejemplo de lo que está filtrando. Dime qué es lo que necesitas en el ejemplo que he puesto para cambiar el filtro a algo más concreto. @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal

Comment: Lo solucione con esta linea de codigo : link.get('href')